# Cannot install react native permissions package

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm trying to install `react-native-permissions` but I always get an error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
```

I read a Github post that said this is an issue with npm 7+, and I need to install legacy peer dependencies, so I installed it like this:
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Tried to `npm I` but still got the same error after that.

Comment: Did you tried ``npm cache clean --force  `` and then  ``npm install``?

also, ``npm install react-scripts -save --force``

Comment: @RohitS I tried now, but still got the same error.

Comment: What is your npm and node version? may be you can try downgrading to the lower version.

Comment: @RohitS NPM is 7.15.1 and Node is 16.3. Wouldn't downgrading the version cause problems with other modules I have already installed?

Comment: @RohitS Thanks! I downgraded npm version (and node version) and now it works just fine.